# Floats and Spacing?

Tags: html, css

So, i placed in many different ways a "logo" and some text next to it. İ would like to leave some breathing room about 10 pixels, however it doesn't seem to work.

İ know that some of my past questions were not well received so i am sorry if this one is as well.

Here is my code, can you help me find out why it wouldn't leave  a space?

CSS:

```
    img {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    float: left;
    }

    body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #F7DE86
    }

    h3, h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-left: 125px;
    }

    h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 55px;
    left: 125px;
    }

    h3 {
    color: #B79104;
    }

    .wrap {
    width: 750px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 130px;
    }
```

Comment: Need to see the relevant HTML that goes along with it. @BrianGerhards, semicolons are property separators in CSS, not terminators. Nothing invalid about leaving them off the last property.

Comment: İ will test it and share my results.

Comment: lol @Brian now please del the comment too which is pointing below..thanx

Comment: <DOCtype! html>
 <html>

  <head>
   <title>İtaliano Facile / Home</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Webpage.css">
  </head>

  <body>
   
   <div class="wrap"

   <aside>

    <span><img src="İmages/LOGO.png"></span>

    <h3>  L'italiano reso facile per voi!</h3>

     <em><h2>  İtaliano Facile</h2></em>

    <h3>  İtalian made easy for you!</h3>
   
   </aside>
 
   </div>

  </body>

 </html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

Use `padding-right` to add some space.
Also read this page for more information
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

I hope that solves your problem.